# Can there exist local maxima or minima at inflection point

Tags: calculus

Assuming that 1st and 2nd derivative exist,
can there be local maxima or minima at inflection point?

What I think is that it cant have maxima or minima because at inflection points the original curve changes its concavity. That why it can either be increasing or decreasing at that point but it cant have any extremum at that point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f(x)$ has a local max or min at $x=0$, then $f'(0)=0$.  Now suppose $f(x)$ has an inflection point at $x=0$.

(case 1)  $f'(x)$ is increasing on $(-\epsilon,0]$ and decreasing on $[0,\epsilon)$.  Then that means $f'(x) \leq 0$ on $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$.  So $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing on $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ so there can't possibly be a local max/min at $x=0$.

(case 2) $f'(x)$ is decreasing on $(-\epsilon,0]$ and increasing on $[0,\epsilon)$.  Then that means $f'(x) \geq 0$ on $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$.  So $f(x)$ is strictly increasing on $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ so there can't possibly be a local max/min at $x=0$.

Comment: I accidently deleted the comment, can I get it back? The thing is that $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 \qquad \text{if } x=0\\\exp{-1/x^2}\sin^2(1/x^2)\end{cases} $$ is indeed differentiable.

Comment: But our reasoning can be made correct. You just have to look at $f'$. An inflection point means that $f'$ has a maximum/minimum there. Now apply your reasoning.

Comment: You say that an inflection point means that $f'$ has a max/min there.  But $f(x)=x^3$ has an inflection point at $x=0$ but doesn't have a max or min.

Comment: It's just not true that $f$ differentiable and $f$ has a maximum on $x_0$ implies that $f'$ is increasing/decreasing around $x_0$.

Comment: The derivative of $x^3$ indeed has a minimum at $0$.

Comment: I agree.  But in my solution, I made the assumption that $f(x)$ has an inflection point at $x=0$.  This is a proof by contradiction.

Comment: You are completely right. Sorry I misread your argument somehow because I was thinking of something similar.

Comment: It's ok.  The derivative of $x^3$ has a minimum at $0$.  In fact this shows that $x=0$ is a point of inflection of $x^3$.  But $x^3$ doesn't have a minimum or maximum since it is a strictly increasing function.

Comment: Bye the way if you drop the differentiability condition there are indeed functions where inflection points exist that are maxima/minima. Example: $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2 \qquad x\leq 0\\x(2-x) \qquad x>0 \end{cases} $$

Comment: @TJCombs so I was right then !!

Comment: You are correct you drop the differentiability condition.  There are also some technicalities in the definition of points of inflection.  Some books say there is a point of inflection at $x_0$ if $f''(x_0)=0$.  However, $f''(x_0)$ exists implies $f'(x_0)$ exists.  So if you take this definition, differentiability at your point of inflection is a necessary condition.  Some books define a point of inflection to be a place $x_0$ where $f'(x)$ changes from increasing to decreasing (or vice versa).  Also, the person who asked the question was only concerned about the case where $f'$ and $f''$ exist

Comment: In the non-differentiable case you just take an inflection point to be a point where the function changes from being convex to being concave.

Comment: And you are right, this is way offtopic. I apologize.